DDD Bounded context diagram as code tools
Building microservices using DDD, CQRS and event-driven paradigm
From the beginning found tool tool to modelling bounded contexts - ContextMapper (https://contextmapper.org/)
This tool covers almost all requirements that I have (aggregate, entities, services definition, bounded contexts relationship, commands and events etc, generation PlantUML diagram etc)
But still have few problems with ContextMapper that aren't implemented in it. For example -multiple repositories for single aggregate, no Query type (for CQRS) and unable to use array (e.g. int[])
All modelling plan to do using diagram as code approach, and ContextMapper uses cml files that can be used for diagram generation
But still looking for a tool that can cover all my requirements. Does anyone know alternative of this tool?
